# chrome displays the wrong source map files

Tags: google-chrome, webpack, webpack-dev-server

After installing the latest dependencies in my React js app built with webpack/webpack-dev-server, chrome is displaying the wrong source map files: showing the content of A.js when I open the file B.js. Any ideea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using. I'm seeing the same in 51.0.2704.106.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a solid fix, but I switched to [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html) and now source maps are working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

For me, upgrading from version 51.0.2704.106 (stable) to 52.0.2743.49 (beta) seems to have fixed it.

This seems to be the relevant Chrome bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=611328

TL;DR: Stable will remain broken until Chrome 52 becomes stable, around July 26th, 2016.